# router -> wax204 AP -> raspberri pi ssh session chain is freezing on certain commands

Tags: networking, ssh, powershell, raspberry-pi, wireless-access-point

I have a standard sky router, with one port connected to a newly configured netgear wax204 Access Point (configured in access point mode), with some peripherals hanging off the access point (including a raspberry pi), via wired ethernet

The devices all have an internet connection, and I can ssh into the raspberry pi via powershell from my pc. However, some commands in powershell cause the session to crash/hang/freeze irrecoverably. For ex, "nano" works fine, "dmesg" crashes the ssh session after 10-20 lines, and "top" crashes immediately every time. the pi itself is not crashing

If I ssh into the pi from a wifi-connected laptop, I have no issues and everything works as expected (everything else is wired)

Also, while I can ssh from powershell, I can't ssh to the pi from putty!

My assumption is there is something misconfigured with the access point but I'm out of my depth trying to fix it... The only settings I seem to have access to are dynamic dns and configuring static routes

Any help much appreciated!

Edit:
I have discovered that ping -l 1458 192.168.0.200 succeeds, but ping -l 1459 192.168.0.200 fails... Is this an implication that there's some mtu settings clash?

Comment: My assumption is there is something misconfigured with the access point   ..............    I do not usually (maybe never) have this kind of problem with an Access point. Try updating the firmware on the AP and reset it to factory defaults and then set it up again.

Comment: The access method to the Pi shouldn't matter, so something might be wrong with the Netgear. Look for a firmware update for the Netgear, or do a factory reset and then redo your settings.

Comment: @John Firmware is latest, updated it this morning while installing it 

I cant for the life of me understand why powershell works but putty doesn't

Comment: I suggest resetting the netgear to factory defaults. If that does not resolve the issue then the Access Point is not the problem.

Comment: @John I haven't changed any settings other than putting it in AP mode instead of router mode, it seems to me that its really unlikely that a reset is going to fix it

Comment: If not the AP then you need to look at all the other devices.  I / we cannot help with that